# dojo require self defined functions version 2

Tags: dojo, amd

I have a problem about requiring my own self defined functions.
In my test.html, I wrote:

```
require(["dojo/query", "new"], function(query, New) {New();});
```

New is the new.js file, which is located in the same place as the dojo folder.
In new.js I wrote:

```
define(["dojo/dom"], function(dom){return dom.byId("d1")});
```

In this case, I can call my New function, when I require it.

But if I change the place of new.js, then when I require "new" again,
there is a dojo Loader error.

if I change the place of new.js, for test.html how should I write it?  Like:

```
require(["dojo/query", "../new"], function(query, New) {...});
```

this did not work.

Does someone know, how to require self defined js file, which is located not in the same place with the dojo folder?

Thanks...

Comment: You should just edit your old question instead of creating a new one that is slightly modified. Now that it is already created I suppose you can just delete your old question.

Comment: ok, i have deleted the old one.

Comment: @throwanerror, I like your screen name.  XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem like this.

First I include dojo in my `<head>` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://myserver.com/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Now dojo can be found in a require.  Just so it is clear, my directory listing of dojo is like this:

`https://myserver.com/dojo/1.7.2/`

[image]

Also you could try [using dojo from a CDN](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/cdn/).

---

Second, I have all my javascript in a folder, `/js`.  When I `require`, I include the folder name like this `"js/MyGrid.js"`.  `js` is deployed into the root of my project on the server.  Now I can `require` like this:

```
require([ "dojo", "dijit/Dialog", "dojo/parser", "dojo/_base/lang",
  "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-class", "js/MyGrid.js", "js/MyUploader.js",
  "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/Textarea", "js/MyJsonHelper.js",
  "dijit/form/SimpleTextarea", "dojox/form/BusyButton", "dojo/dom-attr",
  "dijit/form/Select", "dijit/ProgressBar", "js/MyArray.js", 
  "dojo/domReady!" ], 
  function(dojo, Dialog, parser, lang, query, domClass) {
```

---

**PS:** In no way am I advocating this as a best practice.  It worked for me.  I know there are other ways of doing it, like setting up your **[`data-dojo-config`](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/)** like this:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    packages: [
        { name: "my", location: "js", main: "app" }
    ]
};
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/

Comment: Error: timeout
src: dojoLoader
info: Object {../path/to/my/folder/new.js=1}
fileName: dojo.js

Comment: I tried to change define("[../dojo/dom]"), it does not work also. I think i should use path to point to the dom.js. I read js's source code, because of dependency i really need to change the path. the only solution for me is that i must put myModule(new.js) in the folder of dojo's root folder, if i put it to other places(no relations with dojo) then it does not work. Changing path does not work. why is that?

Comment: @throwanerror Did you define a `dojoConfig` like in Jessemon's example? You should put your javascript files in a folder, e.g. throwanerror/somefile.js, and then define throwanerror's location in the packages array. Also, since you call your module "new", make it doesn't conflict with javascript's `new` keyword.

Comment: I have edited the answer.  Hopefully it is more clear now @throwanerror.  For dojo, just include like you normally would.  It's the same as all the examples and tutorials you see at [dojotoolkit.org/](http://dojotoolkit.org/).  For your own modules, you can use the path starting at `js/` and don't forget to include the `.js` file extension.